# How do I make this recursive method stop once the base case is satisfied?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am given a maze I have to solve using recursion. The maze must place an X wherever it finds an open path (my code does this). It must do so until it reaches an exit using recursive calls (my code does this, EXCEPT, described below). It must *also* place an O wherever it reaches a dead end, draw the Os back to the 'proper' path, and then continue solving along a new path (my code does this).

**HOWEVER**, once it reaches the end of the maze it must then solve a new maze (the original maze, transposed). My problem is as follows:

Once I've reached the end of the maze I receive an IndexOutOfBoundsException. This is expected; I can't continue testing outside the maze bounds! That said, if I try to test for and avoid the exception in any way, the recursive method calls are still on the call stack, and the result is that my method continues to write Os all the way back to the starting point.

I want to simply abort or exit once the exit is reached. I thought my base case would handle that, but it doesn't; it keeps going. I can't perform *any* return from that point, including testing by a base case or by testing during the direction check, because the return creates a situation in which the call stack begins resolving all calls prior to that point. The end result is Os in places there should not be Os, and the recursive method never 'returns' until the call stack is cleared.

Changing the methods to a bool return type does not work. I've tried that. I get the same result. Either I get an exception or I get the Xs being overwritten by Os from the final dead end, past the exit, all the way back to the start.

The maze and my code is below. Please help; I've been working on this same problem for six hours straight and I'm totally stumped.

```
char[,] maze1 = {
            { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
            { '#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.' },
            { '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
            { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' }
        };
```

RECURSIVE METHOD:

```
private void MazeTraversal(char[,] maze, int row, int col)
    {
        if (row < maze.GetLength(0) && col < maze.GetLength(1))
        {
            maze[row, col] = 'X';
            Console.Write(writer.WriteMaze(maze));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);

            #region GoNorth
            // GoNorth
            if (maze[(row - 1), col] == '.')
            {
                MazeTraversal(maze, row - 1, col);
                if (wroteAnO)
                {
                    Console.Write(writer.WriteMaze(maze));
                    wroteAnO = false;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region GoSouth
            if (maze[(row + 1), col] == '.')
            {
                MazeTraversal(maze, row + 1, col);
                if (wroteAnO)
                {
                    Console.Write(writer.WriteMaze(maze));
                    wroteAnO = false;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region GoEast

            if (maze[row, (col + 1)] == '.')
            {
                MazeTraversal(maze, row, col + 1);
                if (wroteAnO)
                {
                    Console.Write(writer.WriteMaze(maze));
                    wroteAnO = false;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region GoWest
            if (maze[row, (col - 1)] == '.')
            {
                MazeTraversal(maze, row, col - 1);
                if (wroteAnO)
                {
                    Console.Write(writer.WriteMaze(maze));
                    wroteAnO = false;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                }
            }
            #endregion


        }
        // if nothing contains a ".", we can't go in any direction. Draw an "O"
        maze[row, col] = 'O';
        wroteAnO = true;
    }
```

Comment: Here and there through your code `wroteAnO` appears magically. It seems to be a feature of the universe that keeps track of characters with holes. If you had another magic value, e.g. `weHaveCompletedTheTaskAtHandSuccessfullyAndNeedOnlyUnwindTheCallStack` you could use it to just "move along, nothing to see here." Or return an enumerated value (`DeadEnd`, `Completed`, `LostInSpace`) and check it to determine the next step.

Comment: Okay. Magic numbers are Bad Things, and I understand that. 

How do I print an O on each step independently of printing an X, and how do I detect that the maze is successfully solved and stop everything?

No code, please. I *want* to understand this within the context of what I have already written.

(....or is what I've already written fundamentally *wrong* and I need to start from the beginning....?)

Comment: It's common for a recursive routine to return either a final value for something like searching a tree or a status for other tasks. I'd probably change the routine to something like `private moveStatusEnum MazeMove( char[,] maze, int row, int col )`. Give it a maze and position and let it return a status. What can happen? `hitWall` ("#"), `alreadyVisited` ("O" or "X"), `deadEnd` (No direction worked.), `outOfBounds` (`row`/`col` out of range), `reachedExit` (Yippee!). Use a `switch` statement to decide what to do for each status: done, try next direction, return `status`, ... .

Comment: I'll remember that in the future, but for now we haven't covered how to use enums in class (and I don't know if we will).  I know *what* you're talking about but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You can replace the `enum` with a `char` and define constant values: `const char hitWall = '#';` and your choice of characters for the others, e.g. visited might be '%' and exit could be '!'. If you haven't covered constants then use comments: `if ( status == '#' ) // Hit wall.`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that the index that's equal to the length of the array is never reached (because the maximal index is always the length-1), so that conditional always gets executed. try changing `if (row < maze.GetLength(0) && col < maze.GetLength(1))` to `if (row < maze.GetLength(0) - 1 && col < maze.GetLength(1) - 1)`

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and the result was the same: after reaching the exit, the call stack continued to resolve and the Os get rewritten over the existing Xs.

I think I have a fundamental problem here. In every other problem like this I've researched, all methods return a bool. Mine doesn't do that, but it doesn't seem to matter- I've tried creating a branch devoted to using return types to manage whether the methods are successful or not, but I still can't evade the IndexOutOfRange exception/call stack issue.